# Failed to install apk on device 'emulator-5554': timeout

Tags: android, eclipse, path, timeout

I am new to Android development. I tried to run LunarLander project (create new project based on sample) in this folder
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows\samples\android-9\LunarLander

But I got this error:
Failed to install LunarLander.apk on device 'emulator-5554': timeout

But if I copied it out to C:\LunarLander, it runs fine. I guess there is something wrong with the path. How do I fix or troubleshoot this?

Comment: I get similar error message, but it doesn't say "timeout" at the end. My project is located at: D:\Eclipse_Projects\workspace\com.folder.game.MyGame There are no spaces. What am I doing wrong???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use spaces in your directory names. If you have files that are in such a directory (e.g., stuff inside of `C:\Program Files\`), copy them to another spot that does not have spaces.

Answer (score 20):

In eclipse, you can increase the timeout. In Eclipse, 
Go to WINDOW-->Prefrences-->android-->DDMS>increase the timeout value. In my case it was 5000 & i incresed it to 10000 & it worked for me .

Answer (score 4):

Close the emulator and launch the APP again. That would fix the issue. You might have kept the emulator open for quite some time without doing any activity.

Restarting the emulator fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

`adb kill-server` and `adb star-server` problem solved.

change time out WINDOW -> Preferences -> android -> DDMS -> increase the timeout value

Answer (score 0):

For me my phone didn't like the USB3.0 port. I moved it to a USB 2.0 port and everything worked fine.