# Failed to install apk on device

Tags: android, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android error: Failed to install *.apk on device *: timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775603/android-error-failed-to-install-apk-on-device-timeout)
>   [Failed to install *.apk on device 'emulator-5554': EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376722/failed-to-install-apk-on-device-emulator-5554-eof)

I m getting to be failed to install apk on device.so let me know how to solve.

**

```
Failed to install MY.Mobile.DMS.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2012-09-18 11:33:41 - MY.Mobile.DMS] (null)
[2012-09-18 11:33:41 - MY.Mobile.DMS] Failed to install MY.Mobile.DMS.apk on device 'emulator-5554': EOF
[2012-09-18 11:33:41 - MY.Mobile.DMS] com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: EOF
[2012-09-18 11:33:41 - MY.Mobile.DMS] Launch canceled!
```

**

Answer (score 1):

check if the AVD is the correct android device i.e whether it is 2.2 or 2.1 and the project is  also on the same platform.Otherwise copy the entire code in a new project and run again on the
the emulator but dis time wait till the emulator setup completes.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

wait for the emulator to setup completely and then test your app. Also, I would leave you AVD open so you dont have to wait so long everytime you run your application.

When it shows the red writing, don't close anything - leave it there and then press the run button again. Worked like a charm.

(OR)

Create another emulator in AVD Manager and try to run your application in the new emulator.

Hope, this will helps you.