# Android emulator not launching the app

Tags: android

i have created an android app at android 4.4. When I launch the emulator, the application icon is visible on the screen but as soon as i click it, it displays an error message-Unfortunately, The New Boston(name of my app) has stopped. 
I have checked the code again n again and it is perfectly fine.
while launching the emulator, console shows the following

```
[2014-03-28 23:33:22 - TheNewBoston] Android Launch!
[2014-03-28 23:33:22 - TheNewBoston] adb is running normally.
[2014-03-28 23:33:22 - TheNewBoston] Performing com.thenewboston.travis.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-03-28 23:33:22 - TheNewBoston] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'avd1'
[2014-03-28 23:33:22 - TheNewBoston] Uploading TheNewBoston.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-03-28 23:33:23 - TheNewBoston] Failed to install TheNewBoston.apk on device 'emulator-5554': EOF
[2014-03-28 23:33:23 - TheNewBoston] java.io.IOException:
```

Comment: Have you launched your app in a real device?, try uninstalling from the emulator.

Comment: Try using http://www.genymotion.com/ emulators instead of the standard eclipse emulators. The website should provide a nice guide to installing the eclipse plugin and installing genymotion; and they tend to run a lot smoother than I've ever had an eclipse emulator run. This could be your problem?

Comment: The only thing to watch for with genymotion, which I too use, is that it can run into conflicts where if you don't close it down properly (as far as adb connections are concerned).

Comment: Try this solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376722/failed-to-install-apk-on-device-emulator-5554-eof

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse there is no virtual device for android ver 4.4 thats why its crashing,you can try genemotion.com emulators