# Can't run demo app with virtual emulator

Tags: android, smartface.io

I am evaluating smartface before buying a license.

I want to get at least one demo app working with the android virtual emulator. However no matter how I try I got this error:

```
Checking Android SDK Configuration.
Emulator found: emulator-5554
Generating Exporting Packages for Android profile:"Default"
Pages, JavaScripts files are preparing
Project resources are preparing
Datasets are preparing
Installation packages are creating
Installing Emulator...
Application could not install to emulator-5554 
Error Message :     pkg: /sdcard/SmartfaceEmulator.apkFailure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_URI]
Please refer to Troubleshooting document!
An error occured on launch! Please launch Smartface Emulator manually on your Android device.
Please refer to Troubleshooting document!
```

I installed `Smartface App Studio 4.4.0.4` on a *fresh new* Windows 10 Enterprise version with all prerequest installed by the Smartface installer. 
Your advice is much appriciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured out myself.
It turned out on my newly created AVD the sdcard is not writable.
Solved it this way...

```
adb shell
mount -o rw,remount rootfs /
chmod 777 /mnt/sdcard
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem you faced doesn't seem to be about Smartface. I think it is about AVD, and there are some other questions about AVD problems.

You can check the below question in order to give a try for the answers:
[Failed to install *.apk on device 'emulator-5554': EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376722/failed-to-install-apk-on-device-emulator-5554-eof)