# Time Out Error in Android App installation

Tags: android

When I try to run my android app,on a samsung galaxy tab in debugging mode, I am getting the below message and unable to run it. What might be the problem? I am using eclipse galileo.

> abc.apk not installed :'timeout'

Comment: Check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775603/android-error-failed-to-install-apk-on-device-timeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eclipse go to Window -> Preferences -> Android -> DDMS and change ADB connection time out (ms) to a bigger value, such as 50000. This works for me.