# Can't install my application to my plugged in device

Tags: android, eclipse

The app I have now runs fine in an emulator but when I try to run it on my Droid 2 I keep getting this message:

```
[2011-07-30 17:29:42 - Mr. Nom] ------------------------------
[2011-07-30 17:29:42 - Mr. Nom] Android Launch!
[2011-07-30 17:29:42 - Mr. Nom] adb is running normally.
[2011-07-30 17:29:42 - Mr. Nom] Performing com.MrNom.NomActivity activity launch
[2011-07-30 17:29:55 - Mr. Nom] Uploading Mr. Nom.apk onto device '015DB9AD17007010'
[2011-07-30 17:30:06 - Mr. Nom] Failed to install Mr. Nom.apk on device '015DB9AD17007010': timeout
[2011-07-30 17:30:06 - Mr. Nom] Launch canceled!
```

Also nothing is showing up in LogCat. Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: Not sure it's a dup, but look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775603/android-error-failed-to-install-apk-on-device-timeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try uninstalling the app completely from your phone using

```
adb uninstall "Mr. Nom.apk"
```

If that doesn't work, try renaming the apk file to mrnom.apk
Also, check to make sure your debugging settings on your phone are enabled correctly.

Comment: ok sorry I'm sort of a noob to this. I have the debugging setting on, but where do I insert the "adb uninstall Mr. Nom.apk"?

Comment: Okay I fixed the problem. I just plugged the cord into a different usb port.