# Eclipse is not recognizing the Nexus one device

Tags: android

Eclipse is not recognizing the google nexus one device. But Usb driver is installed. Because in Android SDK Manager, it is saying Google USB driver package is installed. So why it is not recognizing?? 
I am using Windows XP platform.

Can any one help me please.

Comment: did U checked the enable debugging mode in your mobile settings.

Comment: try adb kill-server and adb start-server then adb devices.

Comment: tried. But still it is not showing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to your device manager and update the driver of the Nexus One to the driver in \android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver. You can find a comprehensive explanation [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html).

Comment: Same way i already did. And in \android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver  it is installed.

Comment: Did you activate USB-debugging on the Nexus One?

Comment: The driver has to be set up in the device manager. Did you really set it up there or did you just look at the folder?

Comment: How to set it up?? Is there any process??

Comment: Yes Not it is recognizing. But when i am try to install the apk it is saying error:
Failed to install SleepWell.apk on device 'HT9CSP820868': timeout

Comment: The answer to this question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775603/android-error-failed-to-install-apk-on-device-timeout

Comment: I tried all the solution, said in the link. But still it is not working.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.
I had the usb driver installed and didn t work.
I solved the problem installing manually the driver.

Open device manager in windows, you should have a yellow icon in Nexus One.
Choose update controller, and choose the folder : \android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver
It should install it.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the USB vendor id? It is there, in develepors.android.com.

- Search for hardware devices in the site
- Add the USB vendor ID in the required file

"Windows > Preference > Android > DDMS," "Adjust connection timeout"; increase the value.

Comment: The Google USB driver for Windows provides support for Nexus one. So is there any need for Vendor ID?

Comment: adb kill-server & adb start-server did you try thiis?

Comment: sorry for the first answer , thought you were using linux machine

Comment: find this page and see if it helps
http://community.developer.motorola.com/t5/Android-App-Development-for/adb-devices-does-not-show-Droid/m-p/10524'
although not regarding nexes one ,please check it..

Comment: Yes Now it is recognizing. But when i am try to install the apk it is saying error: Failed to install SleepWell.apk on device 'HT9CSP820868': timeout

Comment: see the updated answer..voteup and accept if you find it helpful