# Failed to install Hello.apk on device '**': timeout

Tags: android

My apk file is not installing in my Google Nexus phone when i am running from eclipse. it is giving error saying :

"Failed to install SleepWell.apk on device 'HT9CSP820868': timeout"

I tried by power off and on of the phone, Changing the cable, changing the port, increase the time out time. But still it is giving that error.

Can any one help me in this matter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android error: Failed to install \*.apk on device \*: timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775603/android-error-failed-to-install-apk-on-device-timeout)

Answer (score 5):

I have faced the same problem while installing apk of large size.

To solve this problem:

In Eclipse go to `Window -> Preferences -> Android -> DDMS` and change ADB connection time out (ms) to a bigger value, such as 2000 (which i had set earlier to solve this problem), i think default value is 500ms.

Comment: i tried this yesterday. but it was not working. today morning one time it installed.Again it is giving same problem.

Comment: even i tried using command prompt. But still same prob is coming.

Comment: Can anyone really help me out of this problem??