# Application ultimately runs on Emulator but not on device

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

I have been working on an application which is running fine on emulators but not on some devices. I have been testing the application on HTC Desire with OS 2.2 and Samsung Galaxy S with 2.2 and application just runs fine.

Then i had to test the application on Google Nexus phone with OS 4.0.2 to check its comaptibility with latest android OSs, the app does not run. Splash screen starts and then app crashes. This is un-understandable. I have set

```
minSDKVersion to 7 in android manifest
```

Which means that app should run all later OS version from 2.1 onward. I also got problems running application on 4.0.2 and 4.0.3 emulators but I somehow managed to run it on them but not on device Google Nexus.

This is the Error i received:

```
[2012-01-06 17:08:21 - my-app] Failed to install my-app.apk on device 'emulator-5556':    EOF
[2012-01-06 17:08:21 - my-app] java.io.IOException: EOF
[2012-01-06 17:08:21 - my-app] Launch canceled!
```

On emulator for OS 4.x had to increase adb connection timeout and then restarting eclipse worked for me. But what can i do on device..???

Another point to be noted is that this happens only when I try to run the application on 4.x. I haven't used 3.x OS versions. There is no problem running the app in 2.x OS versions.
Any Suggestions and help is always apprciated...????

Comment: can you post the crash log, that will be helpful

Comment: LogCat will be able to tell us and you more about what's happening.

Comment: See the update please. I have solved this on emulator but i don't know what to do with it on device. when apk is installed manually not from eclipse.

Comment: So if you install it from eclipse on device, does it work?

Comment: Yes..But as i told you after going through few steps.

Comment: Refer this Question: [Android error: Failed to install *.apk on device *: timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775603/android-error-failed-to-install-apk-on-device-timeout)

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling Instant Run. Go to your Settings and uncheck Enable Instant run and then launch your app. Hope this will help!