# Failed to install *.apk on device timeout Launch canceled

Tags: android

I read all threads about this problem but the mentioned answers in the threads don't work for me. Can I find out which is the timeoutproblem with the help of a logfile? Is it possible that on my pc are drivers which have problems with the adb? How the adb works in detail if i start the debug process? Can anybody help me with this problem? I spent 16 hours of finding out what the problem is, but the only things I found out are that the problem has nothing to do with the installation of the eclipse, the adt plugin or the android sdk installation. Something with the connection between the emulator or my real device dont work.
If i create a new project and only change the appname or the text in the standard textview, then the app can be launched on the devices. If i do more changes for example create a new layout or something then the app wont work anymore. I am very frustrating in finding out whats wrong with the adb but till now i dont have luck to solve the problem. I hope someone can help me and others with the same problem. thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android error: Failed to install \*.apk on device \*: timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775603/android-error-failed-to-install-apk-on-device-timeout)

Answer (score 20):

In eclipse, you can increase the timeout. In Eclipse, Go to preferences>In the dialog select android>DDMS>increase the timeout value

Answer (score 14):

you could also try to reboot your phone, or restart your adb server

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

it worked for me :)
(increasing timeout value didn't work for me)

Comment: I had to use both answer to solve my timeout problem with the emulator. thanks to everybody.

Comment: This worked for me. I didn't try to increase the timeout in Eclipse. The root problem in my case is because I typed `adb usb` and screwed up the server.