# Android Error: .apk file failed to install on my mobile

Tags: android

Error message is

> failed to install .apk file on to device: timeout

I tried these solutions but did not get any output:

1. Try changing the ADB connection timeout. I think it defaults that to 5000ms and I changed mine to 10000ms to get rid of that problem. If you are in Eclipse, you can do this by going through Window -> Preferences and then it is in DDMS under Android.                                                                              OR
2. I used to have this problem sometimes, the solution was to change the USB cable to a new one                    OR
3. I get this a lot. I'm on a Galaxy S too. I unplug the cable from the phone, plug it back in and try launching the app again from Eclipse, and it usually does the trick. Eclipse seems to lose the connection to the phone occasionally but this seems to kick it back to life.                                                                OR
4. Don't use spaces in your directory names. If you have files that are in such a directory (e.g., stuff inside of C:\Program Files), copy them to another spot that does not have spaces.

Comment: Most importantly, please provide the error message.

Comment: filed to install .apk file on to device :timeout

Comment: Don't have much idea about NFC application..sorry  for that...I thought you might be using app with large database storage..which sometimes shows the error..but might be some problem in memory side.. Try to set your installation location as android:installLocation="preferExternal" in manifest.xml file..might help you out..

Answer (score 0):

Try moving some applications to sdcard. It's maybe your internal storage has not enough space to install a new apk.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This was something related to ADB connection timeout. Just Go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775603/android-error-failed-to-install-apk-on-device-timeout) and tell its working or not.