# Emulator Timeout Error Message while Installing .apk

Tags: android, android-emulator, timeout, apk, adb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android error: Failed to install *.apk on device *: timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775603/android-error-failed-to-install-apk-on-device-timeout)

keep getting error messages when I try to launch any mobile app with android. These errors are not predictable - sometimes (like once out of 10 times) a miracle happens and everything works. But most of the time I get this error:

`[ERROR] C:\Program Files\Titanium Developer\android-sdk-windows\tools\adb.exe 
error: protocol fault (no status)`

followed by this error later on:

`[DEBUG] Waiting for device to be ready ...
[TRACE] adb devices returned 0 devices/emulators
......
[ERROR] Timed out waiting for emulator to be ready, 
you may need to close the emulator and try again`

The emulator starts and I get the locked screen but somehow the connection with it is lost.

I tried launching the emulator separately from a batch file as someone else suggested before I open the ti developer but I get the same errors.

Even if it runs correctly once, if I make changes and want to relaunch (without stopping or closing the emulator) I always get the errors above. I thought we are supposed to be able to keep reusing the emulator once it's up and running but for me it never works like that.

When i try to run from eclipse it used to give the following message `Failed to install Demo.apk on device 'emulator-5554': timeout`

I want to run the same application without killing adb server or without closing the emulator again.

Please any help would be appreciated lot!!!!!!!!!

Comment: hey Read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775603/android-error-failed-to-install-apk-on-device-timeout

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because the default ADB idle time out is 5000ms.

Take `Window -> Preferences -> Android -> DDMS.` Increase your ADB time out. This will solve your problem

Comment: yeah i have got this answer and solved

Answer (score 0):

Delete the .android folder from your home folder of user after closing eclipse and emulator and then restart and try. It should resolve your problem. After deletion you will have to set the sdk of adt plugin.