# Android error : Failed to install : timeout

Tags: android, timeout, apk

Failed to install TempDate.apk on device 'emulator-5554': timeout
Got this error while run my android project. solved by this link [Android error: Failed to install *.apk on device *: timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775603/android-error-failed-to-install-apk-on-device-timeout)

I go step by step but still having the problem..!!

Comment: Set timout longer like 50000,
10000 not work for me at first, i changed it to 50000, problem solved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall your application from your device and then try to run. If the problem continues I think the problem is in your device. Just close and restart. Again it continues then restart your adb and your eclipse.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: i does the same thing.. i am running the project in to emulator. but still having same problem.

Comment: Did you try it with another emulator?

Comment: yeah.. every emulator shows me the same error if i run my project 3-4 times or above..

Comment: Sorry friend. I don't know exactly what is your problem. But I think you have some errors in you android sdk. Try to update it. timeout problem only comes when your emulator doesn't work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the ADB connection timeout. I think it defaults that to 5000ms and I changed mine to 10000ms to get rid of that problem. If you are in Eclipse, you can do this by going through Window -> Preferences and then it is in DDMS under Android.

Comment: i did.. but after running project 3-4 times the emulator shows me the error..

Comment: the trick for me is reinstalling the smartphone drivers, restarting everything and hoping for the best... It's working now

Answer (score 0):

Go to command Prompt and type

adb kill-server

press Enter
Again type

adb start-server

press enter

now clear your project and run....