# Android emulator launch failed

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, ddms

This is the message I get on the console.I have tried to launch it a lot of times, same message. Thanks.

```
[2014-02-07 15:44:08 - david] Performing t.t.Splash activity launch
[2014-02-07 15:44:08 - david] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'slayer'
[2014-02-07 15:44:18 - david] Uploading david.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-02-07 15:44:18 - david] Failed to install david.apk on device 'emulator-5554': Read-only file system
[2014-02-07 15:44:18 - david] com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Read-only file system
[2014-02-07 15:44:18 - david] Launch canceled!
```

Comment: can you show the configuration of your `AVD`?

Answer (score 0):

Change your ADB connection time-out i think that is causing problem.

If you are using eclipse you can go to Window -> Preferences and then it is in DDMS under Android.

Window -> Preferences -> Android -> DDMS -> ADB Connection Timeout (ms)

By default it is 500ms change it to 10000ms.

For more information go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775603/android-error-failed-to-install-apk-on-device-timeout)

Answer (score 0):

This same thing just happened to me because I already had an emulator running.  Make sure you don't already have an emulator running.