# ADT Eclipse - emulator-5554': Read-only file system

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

While Run Android Application in Eclipse, I got the following Error.  How to solve it? I'm very new to ADT.

> Failed to install HaiHello.apk on device 'emulator-5554': Read-only
>   file system
>  [2014-10-16 14:10:59 - HaiHello]
>   com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Read-only file system
>   [2014-10-16 14:10:59 - HaiHello] Launch canceled!

Comment: Did you try with a device ?? can you show the configuration of your `AVD`?

Comment: yes. i directly open the .apk file in android device. its installed and working fine. but i need to work with Eclipse emulator.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21629133/android-emulator-launch-failed)

Comment: My AVD Settings are in following image

http://proimpex.ca/ADV.png

Comment: This should work for you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083709/android-emulator-sdcard-push-error-read-only-file-system

Comment: yes ur right. But there is no solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selecting *Target* as **Android 4.4W** select **Android 4.4.2(api-19)** or **Android L (API20, L Preview)**

**Android 4.4W** is android os for wearable device such as watch.

- [Visit developer site for more info about wear](https://developer.android.com/wear/index.html)
- [Dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)

Comment: While Trying Android 4.4.2(api-19) or Android L <br>
CPU/ABI Options Says "No System image installed for this target"