# Failed to install JudoApp.apk on device 'emulator-5554

Tags: android, eclipse

I have checked my api level of the device and the program i'm creating. I have also restarted my eclipse and the problem still does not seem to resolve. is there any other solutions to this ?

```
[2014-02-15 19:31:39 - JudoApp] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2014-02-15 19:31:39 - JudoApp] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2014-02-15 19:42:15 - JudoApp] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-02-15 19:42:15 - JudoApp] Uploading JudoApp.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-02-15 19:42:16 - JudoApp] Installing JudoApp.apk...
[2014-02-15 19:44:37 - JudoApp] Failed to install JudoApp.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2014-02-15 19:44:37 - JudoApp] (null)
[2014-02-15 19:44:38 - JudoApp] Launch canceled!
```

Comment: Do you get any logcat output from the emulator? Maybe there is a problem with the APK signature. You could also try creating a fresh emulator or wipe the user data of the problematic one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775603/android-error-failed-to-install-apk-on-device-timeout
don't know. maybe this will help

Comment: Maybe SDCard size need to be increased or another emulator hardware setting?

Answer (score 0):

change ADB connection timeout from ddms (default is 5.000,change it to 10.000)