# Eclipse - Target “unknown” in Android device chooser

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

I recently root my htc explorer having OS version 2.3.3, after root i installed OS version 4.4.2. After doing this i am unable to use USB debugging because the Target is set to UNKNOWN. I have tried many tricks but nothing works.

[image]

Comment: I once had the same problem on my Note 8. Even with the latest drivers installed. Eventually, I found that the problem lay on the cable. It was too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here :[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775603/android-error-failed-to-install-apk-on-device-timeout)

1) Try changing the ADB connection timeout. I think it defaults that to 5000ms and I changed mine to 10000ms to get rid of that problem.

If you are in Eclipse, you can do this by going through

Window-> Preferences -> Android -> DDMS -> ADB Connection Timeout (ms)

2)Try to unplug and then again plug the cable. It seems that sometimes eclipse do loose the connection with Device. Sometime you might need to plug in other USB port.

3) You might need to kill adb process and restart it.

adb kill-server and then  adb start-server

Check out [Here](http://www.simplecodestuffs.com/failed-to-install-apk-on-device-timeout-android-error/) as well.

Comment: Worked..Just changed my USB Port..What a tragic problem..Phew