# Android Emulator not working - org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException:

Tags: android, android-emulator, eclipse-adt

I am using Eclipse (ADT), and created a Virtual Android(4.4.2) Nexus device.
I am able to start the Emulator, but when i do Run As > Android Application > Selecting Emulator as target - it fails.. i see following error in logcat (not sure what 10.1.1.100 IP and 9401 port is in the logs):

```
    W/System.err(6599): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /10.1.1.100:9401 timed out
    W/System.err(6599):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
    W/System.err(6599):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:143)
    W/System.err(6599):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
    W/System.err(6599):     at 
        ...
        ...
D/BatteryService(1478): update start
E/yahoo.push.service(6542): yahoo.log.im: Thread-17_im KA exception: prod2.rest-core.msg.yahoo.com
E/yahoo.push.service(6542): java.net.UnknownHostException: prod2.rest-core.msg.yahoo.com
E/yahoo.push.service(6542):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:506)
E/yahoo.push.service(6542):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:294)
E/yahoo.push.service(6542):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:256)
```

If it matters - I am able to run the app successfully on a Physical Device.

**[EDIT 1]**
After clearing the c:\users\meuser\ .android directory:

I still see the following errors:

```
    java.net.UnknownHostException: prod2.rest-core.msg.yahoo.com
    ....
    E/dalvikvm(8793): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.deviceconnection.a.c', 
referenced from method com.google.android.gms.deviceconnection.a.a.<init>
    ...
    Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.util.e.a
```

And ultimately in the console:
Uploading my.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'

```
Installing my.apk...
Installation error: Unknown failure
Please check logcat output for more details.
Launch canceled!
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775603/android-error-failed-to-install-apk-on-device-timeout?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

This is not application issue, issue is with emulator

Try deleting `.android` folder from this path `C:\Users\username\` and create new emulator in your eclipse and try. `.android` folder will be created again.

Comment: Well still no success: Updated the question.. with EDIT 1 . Kindly see

Comment: Change the emulator version and try