# Android Studio Problem | Timed out waiting for process to appear on device

Tags: java, android, ide

I am having the following problem when I try to launch an app on my phone (screenshot attached)

[image: screenshot]

Timed out waiting for process to appear on 'device'...

I am using Android Studio 3.5.3 and I am trying to launch the app on a Huawei P20 Lite with Android 9. I have not used Android Studio since last month and this is the first time I have this problem. I have already tried invalidating cache and restarting and it made no difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android error: Failed to install \*.apk on device \*: timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775603/android-error-failed-to-install-apk-on-device-timeout)

Answer (score 1):

I think there is something wrong with the connectivity of your mobile with laptop.
Mostly it happens due to faulty wire.
Try using a different phone or a different cable.
Hope it works.

Comment: Look at this Q https://stackoverflow.com/q/4775603/3663273        also make sure that developer mode is enabled on your phone and the USB connection mode is set to data transfer or media or something that is not power only or security mode