# Error: ADB exited with exit code 1 Error launching application

Tags: android, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, flutter-packages

1. In pubspec.ymal I added english_words and the
   version to my dependencies list.
2. While viewing the pubspec in Android Studio's editor view, I clicked Packages get which I believed pulled the package into my project.
3. Then in main.dart I imported the package
4. Lastly, I used the english_word to generate text.

**Please help me review and see if there's something I didn't do right.**

```
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final wordPair = WordPair.random();
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text(wordPair.asPascalCase),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your app was correctly compiled/built but it could not be installed on your device. This can have multiple reasons, but as you could see in your terminal; the installation of the actual APK failed.

You should delete any other installations you have of your app, and you should change the ADB connection timeout:

[Android error: Failed to install *.apk on device *: timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775603/android-error-failed-to-install-apk-on-device-timeout)

Answer (score 0):

The problem of insufficient internal memory. After making the free space it successfully installed.